# Lambda and DynamoDB issues

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

I have created a Java Lambda function which is meant to persist to DynamoDB table, deploying with AWS SAM. I observed there are no error logs from the persistence attempt, the Lambda just times out

```
    public static AmazonDynamoDB getDynamoInstance() {
    if (DYNAMO_INSTANCE == null) {
        AmazonDynamoDBClientBuilder amazonDynamoDBClientBuilder = AmazonDynamoDBClientBuilder.standard()
                .withRegion(REGION);
        DYNAMO_INSTANCE = amazonDynamoDBClientBuilder.build();
    }
    return DYNAMO_INSTANCE;
  }


     public void putItemInEventHistory(String event) {
     
 
     DynamoDB dynamoDB = new DynamoDB(DynamoDBFactory.getDynamoInstance());

     Table table = dynamoDB.getTable(EVENTS_HISTORY_TABLE_NAME);

     Item item = new Item()
                .withPrimaryKey("Id", 210)
                .withJSON("event", event);

    PutItemOutcome outcome = table.putItem(item);
       
    
 }
```

Could someone point me in the right direction to troubleshoot.

Cheers
Kris

Comment: check execution role for dynamodb permissions, and for timeout have deployed your lambda in VPC, generally its a network error, and please tell us your timeout duration, try increasing timeout duration

Comment: how are you invoking the lambda? Do you see lambda success/failure metrics in AWS Lambda UI monitoring?

Answer (score 0):

I tested the code and it works with no issue:

```
public class StackOverflow {
    static AmazonDynamoDB DYNAMO_INSTANCE;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        DynamoDB dynamoDB = new DynamoDB(getDynamoInstance());

        Table table = dynamoDB.getTable("testing");

        Item item = new Item()
                .withPrimaryKey("Id", "210")
                .withJSON("event", "{ \"UserID1\": 0, \"UserID2\": 0, \"Message\": \"my message\", \"DateTime\": 0}");

        PutItemOutcome outcome = table.putItem(item);
    }


    public static AmazonDynamoDB getDynamoInstance() {

        if (DYNAMO_INSTANCE == null) {
            AmazonDynamoDBClientBuilder client = AmazonDynamoDBClientBuilder.standard()
                    .withRegion(Regions.EU_WEST_1);

            DYNAMO_INSTANCE = client.build();
        }
        return DYNAMO_INSTANCE;
    }

}
```

- Is your Lambda logging anything? Make sure it has access to logs?
- Does your Lambda have permission to write to DynamoDB?
- Make sure your Lambda has an adequate timeout value
- If you can log and have permissions, try adding some custom logs in the code to understand what is happening at each step.

Comment: I got the error below from the additional logs that I added ...............One or more parameter values were invalid: Missing the key id in the item (Service: AmazonDynamoDBv2; Status Code: 400; Error Code: ValidationException; Request ID: 04PD48FS38N; Proxy: null): com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.model.AmazonDynamoDBException
com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.model.AmazonDynamoDBException: One or more parameter values were invalid: Missing the key id in the item (Service: AmazonDynamoDBv2; Status Code: 400; Error Code: ValidationException; Request ID: 04PD48FS38N; Proxy: null)

Answer (score 0):

it was a stupid mistake....used 'Id' instead of small letters 'id'. But the additional logs did help out

```
log4j.appender.com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2=DEBUG, stderr
```